# How do I set and revise flags/priorities to Agents in Anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbeK0.png)I want to simulate a model where a station processes both virgin and reworked parts. Currently I am able to simulate it in a FIFO manner. (The part from the rework service block and the virgin part assemble in a FIFO manner before the processing station/service block. Any guidelines as to how can prioritize the rework items/agents over the virgin ones?

I have tried creating a variable "priority" whose default value is 2, post rework at a service block (on exit condition), I have tried using agent.priority=1 and then selecting priority based queueing in the Queue block. I am stuck at this point and unable to proceed further as my knowledge of java is modest. Any help or advise would of great help.

Thanks

Deepak

Comment: For me it seems what you did is correct and it's the way I would do it... so you need to explain more details on your model to understand what you are doing wrong

Comment: Hi Felipe, I have pictorially summed the problem I am facing in this link (as I cant attach a picture here) https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbeK0.png                                          I want to prioritize the reworked parts over virgin parts for "service block" as in pic. The agents entering "Rework" are rework items which need to be reprocessed. I then want to examine te cycle time for virgin, rework and both the parts.

Answer (score 0):

From the image provided, it appears that the variable `priority` was created in Main, and not in the Agent as it should have been. This explains the error "priority can not be resolved or is not a field".

Initially, you have set up a simple flow where each agent(part) is generic and indistinguishable from one another. Now you need to differentiate between agents(parts) because of the introduction of rework concept and the priority associated with it. This can be achieved via the creation of custom agent types. You can find much detailed explanation and instruction in Anylogic Help by searching for the term "custom agent".